# How to write a Ecto query that does a group_by MONTH on a datetime field

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am doing a ecto query and am trying to group by `q.created_date`. This query successfully does the GROUP BY but it does it by the second. I am trying to group by month instead.

```
MYQUERY |> group_by([q], [q.created_date, q.id])
```

Is there something like:

```
MYQUERY |> group_by([q], [month(q.created_date), q.id])
```

Comment: Which database are you using? PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `fragment` with [`date_part('month', field)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) to extract the month in PostgreSQL: `fragment("date_part('month', ?)", p.inserted_at))`

```
iex(1)> from(Post) |> select([p], p.inserted_at) |> Repo.all
[debug] QUERY OK db=1.1ms queue=0.1ms
SELECT p0."inserted_at" FROM "posts" AS p0 []
[#Ecto.DateTime<2000-01-01 00:00:00>, #Ecto.DateTime<2000-02-02 00:00:00>,
 #Ecto.DateTime<2000-03-03 00:00:00>, #Ecto.DateTime<2000-04-04 00:00:00>,
 #Ecto.DateTime<2000-04-02 00:00:00>, #Ecto.DateTime<2000-03-02 00:00:00>,
 #Ecto.DateTime<2000-02-02 00:00:00>, #Ecto.DateTime<2000-01-02 00:00:00>]
iex(2)> from(Post) |> group_by([p], fragment("date_part('month', ?)", p.inserted_at)) |> select([p], count("*")) |> Repo.all
[debug] QUERY OK db=1.7ms
SELECT count('*') FROM "posts" AS p0 GROUP BY date_part('month', p0."inserted_at") []
[2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Just make sure you mind the difference between `date_part` and `date_trunc`. Use trunc for non-overlapping groupings.

Comment: This isn't really helpful since you don't know what index in the return array refers to what month.

Comment: @AlxVallejo, you just need to select an identifier beside the aggregation, you can actually select the fragment that you grouped by as such identifier, check my answer above for an example.

Answer (score 2):

Using Dogbert's answer and arvidkahl's excellent hint, it's possible to group by the month without ambiguity on the fragment dimension using the following:

```
from q in query,
  join: i in Item,
  on: i.id == q.item_id,
  group_by: [i.category_id, fragment("date_trunc('month', ?)", q.inserted_at)],
  select: %{category_id: i.category_id, date: fragment("date_trunc('day', ?)", q.inserted_at), quantity: sum(q.quantity)}
```