# Ecto query that does a group_by MONTH on a datetime field and returns list of tuples

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

As a tag-along question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648371/how-to-write-a-ecto-query-that-does-a-group-by-month-on-a-datetime-field):

How would you alter the query to return a list of tuples with the integer of the month and the grouped count? So your result would look like:

```
[{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {4,2}]
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the other question.

Comment: You should consider posting the answer in case someone else has a similar need to your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just porting this from the comments on the question.

```
query 
|> group_by([e], fragment("date_part('month', ?)", e.inserted_at)) 
|> select([e], {fragment("date_part('month', ?)", e.inserted_at), count(e.id)}) 
|> Repo.all
```

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a DRYer solution for this?

Comment: @StevePallen You can DRY it up a bit by putting the `fragment` into a custom macro (https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1-defining-custom-functions-using-macros-and-fragment)

Comment: Thanks @MikeBuhot that would help a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

```
query 
|> group_by([e], fragment("date_part('month', ?)", e.inserted_at)) 
|> select([e], {fragment("date_part('month', ?)", e.inserted_at), count(e.id)}) 
|> Repo.all
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit more clearer.

```
query = from u in User,
  group_by: fragment("date_part('month', ?)", u.inserted_at),
  select:   {fragment("date_part('month', ?)", u.inserted_at), count(u.id)}
Repo.all(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also name the fragment like this.

```
User
|> group_by(fragment("month"))
|> select([u], {fragment("date_part('month', ?) as month", u.inserted_at), count(u.id)})
|> Repo.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this, since I was getting float return values (like. 6.0 instead of 6)

```
User
|> group_by(fragment("month"))
|> select([u], {fragment("date_part('month', ?)::int as month", u.inserted_at), count(u.id)})
|> Repo.all()
```